# Why To Care About Parity?

Tags: particle-physics, parity

I was reading the following article on wikipedia :- [Wu Experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wu_experiment#cite_note-LedermanHill2013-19).

The excerpt from that article is - "If a particular interaction respects parity symmetry, it means that if left and right were interchanged, the interaction would behave exactly as it did before the interchange. Another way this is expressed is to imagine that two worlds are constructed that differ only by parity — the "real world" and the **"mirror world"**, where left and right are swapped. If an interaction is parity symmetric, it produces the same outcomes in both "worlds""

Now, My question is that why are we caring about what is going in that **"mirror world"** when we live in say - the real world? Or Why to care about parity?

Answer (score 3):

The importance of the experiment was not to demonstrate the difference in a fictional world that cannot be measured experimentally. The 'mirror world' scenario is simply to explain how the parity transform acts on spacetime. Instead, the experiment shows that the weak interaction only involves the left (resp. right) -handed part of leptons and quarks (resp. antileptons and antiquarks). This has led to constraints being placed on the Standard Model, e.g. that massless neutrinos must be left-handed - constraints that have ramifications in how we develop theories to model the real world.

Another fun implication is that, since $\mathbf{P}$-symmetry is violated, it is possible to distinguish 'left' and 'right' without ambiguity, which also means that we can communicate with distant aliens to verify if they're made of matter or antimatter - see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Elt0Gt9Cb6Q) enjoyable minutephysics video.